# MooTools: Parsing Ajax responseTree

Tags: javascript, xml, rss, mootools, xmlhttprequest

I have an Ajax request to an XML document. The XML document is an RSS feed. Here's my `onSuccess` for the request:

```
onSuccess: function(responseTree) {
 // process <item> elements
}
```

How do I enumerate `<item>` elements and retrieve the various child values?

Answer (score 1):

The success-event returns an XML-object as well, if the content type of the called file is set to `text/xml`. However, beware of that this is not possible if you're calling a file on another server - it's not cross-domain. You can only use the Request-object to call files on the same domain.

Example code that enumerats through the `item` elements;

```
new Request({
    url: '/your-rss-parser.php',
    method: 'get',
    onSuccess: function(responseText, responseXML) {
        responseXML.getElements('item').each(function(item) {
            alert(item.getElement('title').get('text'));
        });
    }
}).send();
```

Comment: So what is the right way to retrieve and parse an RSS feed in javascript, since feeds will usually be from another server?

Answer (score 0):

I'm having trouble getting Björn's solution to work in a class. I've got XML

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
    <countries>
        <country>
            <name>Argentina</name>
            <id>1</id>
        </country>
        <country>
            <name>Australia</name>
            <id>2</id>
            <climate>Hot</climate>
        </country>
        <country >
            <name>France</name>
            <id>3</id>
        </country>
    </countries>
```

and JS

```
    var requestXML = new Class({

    initialize: function(){
        var req = new Request({
            method: 'post',
            autoCancel: true,
            url: 'data.xml',
            onSuccess: function(text, xml){
                xml.getElements('country').each(function(country) {
                    alert(item.getElement('country').get('text'));
            });
            }.bind(this)
        }).send();
    },

});     

window.addEvent('domready', function() {

    var request = new requestXML();

});
```

But the script doesn't do getElement on the xml object - Chrome complains "Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'getElement'".

I did get this other version working in Chrome (having read about the mysterious Slick methods [in this post](http://groups.google.com/group/mootools-users/browse_thread/thread/b2cae93ff83617f3/0a1f41e89d2feff0))

```
    var requestXML = new Class({

    initialize: function(){
        var req = new Request({
            method: 'post',
            autoCancel: true,
            url: 'data.xml',
            onRequest: function(){
                //
            }.bind(this),
            onSuccess: function(text, xml){
                this.parseXML(xml);
            }.bind(this),
            onFailure: function(transport){
                alert('XML loading error');
            }
        }).send();
    },

    parseXML: function(xml){
        var firstCountry = Slick.find(xml, 'country name');
        // Finds first matching element
        // Returns <name>Argentina</name>
        var countries = Slick.search(xml, 'country');
        // Finds all matching elements
        // Returns [<country>...</country>, <country>...</country>, ... ]
        var output = '';
        countries.each(function(item, index){
            var id = item.getElement('id').get('text');
            var name = item.getElement('name').get('text');
            var climate = item.getElement('climate');
            if (climate){
                climate = climate.get('text');
            } else {
                climate = '';
            }
            output += id + ' ' + name + ' ' + climate + '<br>';
        });
        $('container').set('html', output);
    }

});     

window.addEvent('domready', function() {

    var request = new requestXML();

});
```

But it breaks in IE, which says "Object doesn't support this property or method" on the line `var id = item.getElement('id').get('text');`. This looks similar to the problem with getElement() in the Björn style solution.

Can anybody advise us? The documentation for Mootools seems poor in comparison with JQuery, and I can't find much useful info about how to parse XML.

Cheers
And Finally

Comment: Check your RSS feed to make sure there is an element called ID.